# i am having a problem importing to_categorical from tensorflow.keras.utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

Pycharm gives me the following error: Cannot find reference 'to_categorical' in '**init**.py'`
these are the packages i have installed as seen in python interpreter:

```
Kivy    2.2.1   2.3.0
Kivy-Garden 0.1.5   0.1.5
Markdown    3.5.2   3.5.2
MarkupSafe  2.1.5   2.1.5
absl-py 2.1.0   2.1.0
app 0.0.1   0.0.1
astunparse  1.6.3   1.6.3
cachetools  5.3.3   5.3.3
certifi 2023.11.17  2024.2.2
charset-normalizer  3.3.2   3.3.2
contourpy   1.2.0   1.2.0
cycler  0.12.1  0.12.1
dm-tree 0.1.8   0.1.8
docutils    0.20.1  0.20.1
flatbuffers 23.5.26 23.5.26
fonttools   4.49.0  4.49.0
gast    0.5.4   0.5.4
google-auth 2.28.1  2.28.1
google-auth-oauthlib    1.2.0   1.2.0
google-pasta    0.2.0   0.2.0
grpcio  1.62.0  1.62.0
h5py    3.10.0  3.10.0
idna    3.6 3.6
joblib  1.3.2   1.3.2
kivy-deps.angle 0.3.3   0.4.0
kivy-deps.glew  0.3.1   0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2  0.6.0   0.7.0
kiwisolver  1.4.5   1.4.5
libclang    16.0.6  16.0.6
markdown-it-py  3.0.0   3.0.0
matplotlib  3.8.3   3.8.3
mdurl   0.1.2   0.1.2
ml-dtypes   0.3.2   0.3.2
namex   0.0.7   0.0.7
numpy   1.25.2  1.26.4
oauthlib    3.2.2   3.2.2
opt-einsum  3.3.0   3.3.0
packaging   23.2    23.2
pandas  2.2.1   2.2.1
pillow  10.2.0  10.2.0
pip 22.3.1  24.0
protobuf    4.25.3  4.25.3
pyasn1  0.5.1   0.5.1
pyasn1-modules  0.3.0   0.3.0
pygments    2.17.2  2.17.2
pyparsing   3.1.1   3.1.1
pypiwin32   223 223
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0 2.9.0.post0
python-version  0.0.2   0.0.2
pytz    2024.1  2024.1
pywin32 306 306
requests    2.31.0  2.31.0
requests-oauthlib   1.3.1   1.3.1
rich    13.7.1  13.7.1
rsa 4.9 4.9
scikit-learn    1.4.1.post1 1.4.1.post1
scipy   1.12.0  1.12.0
setuptools  65.5.1  69.1.1
six 1.16.0  1.16.0
tensorboard 2.15.2  2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2   0.7.2
tensorflow  2.15.0  2.15.0.post1
tensorflow-estimator    2.15.0  2.15.0
tensorflow-intel    2.15.0  2.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.31.0  0.36.0
termcolor   2.4.0   2.4.0
threadpoolctl   3.3.0   3.3.0
typing-extensions   4.10.0  4.10.0
tzdata  2024.1  2024.1
urllib3 2.1.0   2.2.1
werkzeug    3.0.1   3.0.1
wheel   0.38.4  0.42.0
wrapt   1.14.1  1.16.0
```

i tried many variations of the import, none worked. i have all the neccessary packages installed as far as i know, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

That function exists in `tensorflow.keras.utils`, not `tensorflow.python.keras.utils`.

Try:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

Comment: doesn't work, gives these errors: Cannot find reference 'keras' in '__init__.py | __init__.py', and Unresolved reference 'to_categorical'

Comment: @SivanUziel Those are not standard python messages, are they made by an IDE?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy These are not messages I get when running the code, these are errors/warnings that pycharm gives

Comment: @SivanUziel That should be mentioned in the question, as those messages are not really a problem in the code, its just pycharm being confused by tensorflow.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy These are errors, to clarify, that pycharm gives. The code doesn't run while these are errors because it cant find a  module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Comment: @SivanUziel The code would run if you run it in python, try that, outside pycharm.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, doesn't run outside of pycharm, i tried

Comment: @SivanUziel And what happens? what errors do you get?

Comment: I tested this with pycharm, it shows the errors `Cannot find reference 'keras' in 'init.py | init.py'` and `Unresolved reference 'to_categorical'` in the editor, but the code runs without errors if you run it.